# What this 400 bad req is actually asking for ion my apollo client query?

Tags: graphql, frontend, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm running this exact same query on apolloStudio and the response it's correct but in the code I'm getting a 400 bad req, I assume that the syntax is wrong, and it's quite complex given the fact that I'm querying an input inside a query. Here's an image of the response in apolloStudio:
[image]
Here's the code:

```
const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(
      gql`
        query GetUser(
          $id: String
          $ratingHistoryFilter: userRatingHistoryFilterInput
        ) {
          getUser(_id: $id) {
            _id
            ratingHistory(ratingHistoryFilter: $ratingHistoryFilter) {
              rating
              date
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      {
        id: props.uid,
        ratingHistoryFilter: {
          dateFrom: '1994-06-24',
          verified: 'false',
          dateTo: '2022-07-06',
          userID: {
            condition: 'EQUAL',
            value: '62c2d4100892074470ca374e'
          }
        }
      }
    )

    console.log(result)
    const userData = computed(() => result.value?.getUser ?? {})
    console.log(userData.value)
```

Here's the console error:
[image]

**This is the network response**:
{"errors":[{"message":"Variable "$id" of type "String" used in position expecting type "String!".","code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"},{"message":"Variable "$ratingHistoryFilter" of type "userRatingHistoryFilterInput" used in position expecting type "userRatingHistoryFilterInput!".","code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}]}